# Creating a temporary nameless class instance in C++

Tags: c++

Sometimes I need to instantiate a class only to call its one methed. For example to read registry in Qt.

```
QSettings settings;
settings.setValue( DEST_FOLDER, destDir );
```

But I use this syntax instead.

```
QSettings().setValue( DEST_FOLDER, destDir );
```

It works but I haven't seen any documentation on it, what is it called? I searched 'nameless c++ class' but it doesn't come up. There is anonymous class but I think that's different.

My question is its a little like calling the constructor..is there a name to this kind of syntax? Can someone explain or point me to documentation to this kind of initialization? Dumb question but is it bad to do this?

Comment: You're describing a "temporary", or "r-value"

Comment: The class is neither nameless (It's called `QSettings`) nor temporary (it's there and it will always be there).

Comment: Kerrick SB is likely hinting that you may be confusing the terms "class" and "instance"

Comment: Not the class is 'nameless', but the temporary variable used in `QSettings().setValue( DEST_FOLDER, destDir );` (Doing it is OK)

Comment: whoever has voted down my question must know you are against spreading knowledge :)

Comment: Why exactly is my question beng down voted..may I know the reason please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
QSettings().setValue( DEST_FOLDER, destDir );
```

will give you a default constructed temporary *instance* of `QSettings` that will exist until the end of the full expression, in this case the `;` at the end of the line, and then call `setValue(...)` on said temporary.

You can call every constructor you want this way, not just the default constuctor as you did in your example. If e.g. `class A` has a constructor and a member function `fun` that take a single `int`,

```
A(5).fun(20);
```

will create a temporary object of type `A` via `A::int(5)` and then call `A::fun(int i)` with `i = 20` on it.

This is allowed and safe, whether this actually makes sense depends on what the method you call does in the end.

Note that the class itself is neither nameless nor temporary, only the instance you create is.

Comment: So basically you can call any constructor like this! This is what I wanted to know, it almost behaves like the constructor is static..well constructor is special but I have never seen this in any documentation that you can invoke a nameless class instance like this.

Comment: @zadane Well a constructor is not really `static`, but it does of course not need an existing instance to be invoked on since it is the mechanism to create an instance in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> *"My question is its a little like calling the constructor..is there a name to this kind of syntax?"*

Yes, it's called a creating a *temporary rvalue*

> *"Can someone explain or point me to documentation to this kind of initialization?"*

It's a basic c++ feature, documentation may be given in the [C++ standard specification](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf).

> *"Dumb question but is it bad to do this?"*

Totally depends on what features [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) actually provides, and these kind of calls persist the settings, as you want to do.